# R: Two-Way Repeated-Meausre ANOVA with only a selection of conditions

Tags: r, anova, two-way

Two-Way repeated-measure ANOVA using not all possible values of one categorical variable.

Dear community,
I have a data frame, that looks something like this (This is only an example data set, so there can be no useful results been found in this data set. ):

```
ID condition side value
01 B left 13
01 C left 20
01 A left 9
01 C right 23
01 A right 11
01 B right 17
02 C left 18
02 A left 7
02 B left 12
02 A right 11
02 B right 15
02 C right 20
```

ID is the participant number. There are two factors that define the condition of this repeated measure design (condition, side). They are the categorical variables. Value is the depended variable.
So I ran a two-Way repeated-meausre ANOVA like this:

```
library(dplyr)

is.factor(data$condition) #FALSE
is.factor(data$side) #FALSE
Copy_data_factor <- data %>%
    convert_as_factor(condition, side)
is.factor(Copy_data_factor$condition) #TRUE
is.factor(Copy_data_factor$side) #TRUE

#Two-Way repeated-measure ANOVA
res.aov <- anova_test(
    data = Copy_data_factor, dv = value_1, wid = ID, within = c(condition, side)
     )
get_anova_table(res.aov)

#Output: Mauchly’s test of sphericity
res.aov
```

I guess I can calculate the analysis this way.

Now, I would like to run a two-way repeated ANOVA again but not with condition A, B and C. Instead only conditions B and C should be considered during this analysis. Has anyone an idea, how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You could just reduce the dataframe to only keep rows with the desired conditions, and then run the ANOVA over this new dataframe:

```
Copy_data_new <- Copy_data_factor[which(Copy_data_factor[["condition"]] %in% c("b", "c")),]
```

Comment: This code doesn't work. I always receive a data frame with 0 observations.

Comment: It works for me given your example above. There might be an issue with missing values. I have adapted the code above to account for that, try if that works for you